# How to solve 1D heat equation using neural networks in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, ode, pde

I want to solve a 1D heat conduction using neural netwroks in pytorch. The PDE represeting the heat conduction is as follows:

```
du/dt = k d2u/dx2
```

where, `k` is a constant, `u` represent temperature and `x` is also the space. I also include a boundary condition like `0` temperature at `x=0` and initial condition like `t=0`. I am quite new in the field of PINN and only can solve normal ODEs with it. The following code is tryin to solve a very simple ODE like `du/dx=u` with boundary condition like `u=0` at `x=0`. The answer is simply `u = u2/2`. The following code is a simple PINN that solve this ODE:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
# N is a Neural Network with three layers
N = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 50), nn.Sigmoid(), nn.Linear(50,1, bias=False))
BC = 0. # Boundary condition
g_f = lambda x: BC + x * N(x) # a general function satisfying the BC
f = lambda x: x # Undolvable ODE!!! : du/dx = x ----> u = x2/2
# The loss function
def loss(x):
    x.requires_grad = True
    outputs = g_f(x)
    grdnt = torch.autograd.grad(outputs, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(outputs),
                                  create_graph=True)[0]
    return torch.mean((grdnt - f(x)) ** 2)
optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(N.parameters())
x = torch.Tensor(np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)[:, None])
# Run the optimizer
def closure():
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    l = loss(x)
    l.backward()
    return l  
for i in range(10):
    optimizer.step(closure)
x_test = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)[:, None]
with torch.no_grad():
    y_test = g_f(torch.Tensor(x_test)).numpy()
```

How to replicate the code with 1D heat conduction?

Comment: Common solvers are quick and have a controllable error behavior. What is the motivation to dive into the vagaries of neuronal networks? // Also, first perform the step from simple quadrature to ODE solutions. Then to ODE solutions of systems, which includes method-of-lines for PDE. Then explore how the interpretation of PDE solutions as functions evolving in time can be used for more specific NN approaches.

Comment: Dear @LutzLehmann, Thanks for your hints. As the complexity of the problems increases, solvers get more and more time demanding. This is the reason I want to try NN for solving a PDE.

Comment: Well, good luck. I have yet to see a reasonable approach to solving ODE via ANN. What is mostly found is to replace RNN with a similar ODE system, but using standard ODE solvers for it.